# Printing in CIL (OCaml)

Tags: ocaml, berkeley-cil

I would like to print CIL structures e.g. `Cil.instr`
According to the CIL API, it has a function like e.g. `Cil.d_instr`, which I can use to print to the Errormsg like e.g. `Errormsg.log "Instruction: %a\n" d_instr i;`
I would like to store it value in a variable. I tried:

```
  let i_str = Printf.sprintf "%a" Pretty.sprint (d_instr i) in ...
```

however, this causes type mismatch compiling error. 
Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `Cil.d_instr` has the following prototype:

```ml
val d_instr : unit -> instr -> Pretty.doc
```

Therefore, to get a value of type `Pretty.doc`, you need to apply a value of type `unit` before the instruction: `d_instr () i`.

Then, to convert a `Pretty.doc` to a `string`, you need to use `Pretty.sprint : width:int -> doc -> string`. Note that you need to provide a maximal width (but you can use a very large one if you wish). Finally, combining both parts, you get:

```ml
let i_str = Pretty.sprint max_int (Cil.d_instr () i)
```

I suggest you to read carefully the documentation of `Pretty`: http://kerneis.github.io/cil/doc/html/cil/api/Pretty.html. It will explain you in particular that it is more efficient to use values of type `Pretty.doc` as long as possible, concatenating values with `(++)`, and translating to a string (or sending to standard output) only at the very end.

Finally, but this is unnecessarily complex in my opinion, here is how to compose it if you really want to use `Printf.sprintf`:

```ml
  let ds_instr () i = Pretty.sprint max_int (Cil.d_instr () i) in
  let i_str = Printf.sprintf "%a" ds_instr i in ...
```